# Download a file to local file system using Phonegap showing a progress bar

Tags: html, cordova, download

I have a Phonegap app (iOS & Android) that needs to download some fairly large files. I'm able to using FileTransfer.download() to successfully download the files. However, since the files are so large I would like to be able to show the download progress. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately [that API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) doesn't provide a progress callback..

You might want to try instead the XmlHttpRequest way in order to download your file ('GET' action on your file), there seems to be a [progress event](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress) there!
Using a BlobBuilder you could then store this downloaded file using the File API.